# Using master pages with normal Pages documents in Pages 7.0

Tags: pages

The Pages 7.0 updated released yesterday (March 27, 2018) includes the ability to have [master pages](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207243) in your Pages documents. I read their [support article](https://help.apple.com/pages/mac/7.0/#/tan1959e234e) on creating and using master pages, but I'm unable to find the master pages option. You are supposed to press the leftmost button on the toolbar, but it doesn't say "Edit Master Pages" in any of the options. There is an "Edit Master Pages" option in the "View" menu, but it seems to be grayed out for all of my documents. Master Pages should be usable for Pages documents as well as books. I can't seem to get the "Edit Master Pages" option in the View menu to "ungray," – even when trying to create a template or load one.

Could anyone explain how to use this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this report](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8335594), the feature can only be used with Layout docs.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you be more specific as to what you mean by Layout docs?

Comment: @esaruoho. File > Convert to Page Layout